# React, saving mouse coords in state causes window to scroll to the top, how to solve?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm using Handsontable for my grid in an application. When a user clicks on the grid, I want to save the mouse coordinates in state, which I use later to properly position a modal window.

The grid comes with a stand mousedown event and I'm just setting state like this:

```
      this.setState({x: events.clientX, y: events.clientY})
```

However, if I am scrolled down on the page, and I click, it immediately scrolls the window back to the top. This only happens when I'm using this setState for the events. If I console log them for example, it doesn't scroll back to the top.

How can I stop the window from scrolling to the top here?

Comment: You need to provide more code for people to allow others to help you. There is no way anyone can asses the issue from a single line showing state being set. What other events are bound to the x and y properties in the state?

Comment: javascript  typically assigns values by reference, meaning all your variables will point to the same object in memory. I wonder if you properly clone the object, if it would work as you not mutate the real coordinates. Can you try: ` this.setState({...{x: events.clientX, y: events.clientY}})`

Comment: when you change state the component should re-render. Do you think that might cause scroll to the top?

Comment: wait, is your button actually a link `<a>` and its href is `#` ? This will make your page scroll to top, in any case.

Comment: It's seems if I take any action on the event, like calling a method, the window scrolls. So it doesnt' have to do with the mouse events per say...it's when I take some action when the mouse event occurs. I will see if I can create a simple page that reproduces the behavior i'm seeing and update with more code.